# SQL server 2016 Getting distinct results when only limited to a where statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

I am looking for a distinct list of the CUSTOMER_NAME field from my table. Normally I would simply do

```
SELECT 

      distinct 
         [CUSTOMER_NAME]

  FROM [iData3].[dbo].[N241650]
```

or

```
SELECT 

         [CUSTOMER_NAME]

  FROM [iData3].[dbo].[N241650]

Group by [CUSTOMER_NAME]
```

But I am limited in my query. Due to software restrictions, the query can only be of the form

```
SELECT * from 
[iData3].[dbo].[N241650] 
where ...
```

How do I get a distinct list of customer names given these restrictions? I essentially need to cram everything into the WHERE clause. I'm thinking possibly WHERE EXISTS or NOT EXISTS but I haven't used those conditions before so I'm not certain if they'd be useful.

This is not possible because... is acceptable if the disappointing answer.

Comment: Use a subquery where you give each record a rank (e.g. `ROW_NUMBER`), and use the `WHERE` of the outer select to only select records with rank=1.

Comment: My idea (if you can work in from field too) is like this: `select * from (select distinct customer_name from <your_table>) where 1=1 --if you need the where clause in outer query`

Comment: You need a key to do this. Can't do with entirely duplicate rows.

Comment: You could also cheat using `UNION`, it has an implicit distinct. Considering the options, this is an ugly work around though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` function :

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES [CUSTOMER_NAME]
FROM [iData3].[dbo].[N241650]
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_NAME ORDER BY ?)
```

`?` indicates something *identity* or *primary/unique* column which you have.

Comment: The question mark can be replaced by anything, really. I don't think op cares about which row is chosen, it can even be `CUSTOMER_NAME` again.

Comment: if he dont want to order it with anything then op can very well use the (select 1) at the ? place.

Answer (score 0):

You need something unique in each row.  If you have that, you can use:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_NAME
FROM [iData3].[dbo].[N241650]
WHERE pk = (SELECT MIN(n2.pk)
            FROM [iData3].[dbo].[N241650] n2
            WHERE n2.CUSTOMER_NAME = N241650.N241650
           );
```

`pk` is the unique column.

Comment: How could this possibly attract a downvote, given that it correctly answers the OP's question?

Answer (score 0):

You can group by that column to achieve the same result.

```
select CUSTOMER_NAME 
from ...
group by CUSTOMER_NAME
order by CUSTOMER_NAME;
```

Another alternative is to use a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't escape from the `*`, then you can't `GROUP BY` and if you just have a `WHERE` then you will need a key (unique set of columns) to be able to filter correctly or else you can't differentiate dupicates (and end up selecting more than 1 row with the same customer name).

It's a bit convoluted, but try with this. It will get you 1 row per each `CUSTOMER_NAME`.

```
SELECT 
    * 
from 
    [iData3].[dbo].[N241650] 
where 
    [N241650].KeyColumn IN
    (
        SELECT
            Z.KeyColumn
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    X.KeyColumn,
                    Ranking = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY X.CUSTOMER_NAME ORDER BY X.KeyColumn ASC)
                FROM
                    [iData3].[dbo].[N241650] AS X
                WHERE
                    X.KeyColumn IS NOT NULL
            ) AS Z
        WHERE
            Z.Ranking = 1
    )
```

The `ORDER BY` inside the `OVER` will determine which row you get for each `CUSTOMER_NAME`.

If you have multiple columns for your key, then you will have to switch the `IN` for an `EXISTS` against multiple columns (you can't do a multiple column `IN` in SQL Server).

```
SELECT 
    * 
from 
    [iData3].[dbo].[N241650] 
where
    EXISTS (
        SELECT
            'key columns match'
        FROM (
            SELECT
                X.KeyColumn1,
                X.KeyColumn2,
                Ranking = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY X.CUSTOMER_NAME ORDER BY X.KeyColumn1 ASC)
            FROM
                [iData3].[dbo].[N241650] AS X
            ) AS Z
        WHERE
            Z.Ranking = 1 AND
            [N241650].KeyColumn1 = Z.KeyColumn1 AND
            [N241650].KeyColumn2 = Z.KeyColumn2
    )
```